# RAM no longer working after adding a second stick

Tags: laptop, memory, hardware-failure

I have a Dell XPS 15 9500, and I'm trying to add 8GB of RAM.

I have RAM stick 1 and RAM stick 2. RAM 1 came with the laptop, and RAM 2 I bought on amazon. Here's what's written on them:

RAM 1:

- MTA8ATF1G64HZ-3G2J1
- 8GB 1RX8 PC4-3200AA-SA2-11
- DPAPTJM002
- 2037

RAM 2:

- HMA81GS6DJR8N-XN NO AC
- 8GB 1RX8 PC4-3200AA-SA2-11 <- This is what I matched because I have no idea what I'm doing
- 2014

The problem is, I added RAM 2, and got the error code for RAM failure. Next, I took out RAM 2, still RAM failure. Then I tested RAM 2 alone in both slots and it works fine. RAM 1, which I've been using for over a year, now does not work in either slot.

Why isn't RAM 1 working anymore? I don't think I damaged it.

Comment: `I don't think I damaged it.` Did you take electrostatic discharge precautions? A few thousand volts surging through it, can kill it.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Please don't write 'solved' & the answer in the question. This isn't reddit. John gave you the answer. Following it fixed your issue, so you mark it as accepted. Done. Comment underneath by all means. If it didn't fix your issue & you found another better method yourself, make that a new answer.

Comment: `How do you do that?` by moving about, Desco have some wonderful videos on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't RAM 1 working anymore? I don't think I damaged it.

That is hard to say since you started back with the original memory.

The memory may not have been properly seated. Try once more to ensure the memory is properly seated.

Otherwise, at this point, you might see if you can return the memory and then get the computer serviced at your local shop. This is most likely the best course of action.